# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql, apache, pdo, php-7

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server that we can access through "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio":

[image]

I've tried a bunch of different things I've seen on SO but nothing has worked. I get the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test.php:52 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test.php on line 52` when running the following code on the `test.php` page:

```
$serverName = "SERVER.DOMAIN.COM, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB_NAME", "UID"=>"USER", "PWD"=>"PASS");
$ma_conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $ma_conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

My php.ini file has gone through many different extensions being enabled, but none have worked. I've tried all of the following:

```
extension = php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Currently I have:

```
extension_dir = "c:\apache24\php7\ext\"
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

On the machine with Apache and PHP in CMD I get the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>php -c c:\apache24\php7\php.ini -v -display_startup_errors=1

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\apache24\php7\ext\ php_pdo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\apache24\php7\ext\ php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0 PHP
Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\apache24\php7\ext\ php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 09:48:53) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I've also downloaded and ran `SQLSRV32.EXE` inside of the `C:\Apache24\php7\ext` folder.

I have:

- Windows Server 2012 RS win64
- Apache 2.4.23 win64
- PHP 7.0.10 win64
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client win64
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 & x86 Redistributables (two different)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributables (x64 & x86) - 14.0.23026
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Conform to the list of your tries in php.ini (`php_sqlsrv_XX_ts.dll`), you have activated extensions for PHP v5.5 and v5.6. But, since you are running PHP 7.0, you need to download and activate the corresponding [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). It seems that you need to download the **driver version 4.0**. This is stated on the [php.net page for SQLSRV extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php#intro.sqlsrv).

> The SQLSRV extension is supported by Microsoft and available for
>   download here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.

Here you can find the instructions for [Loading the PHP SQL Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver). You'll probably receive a file like `php_sqlsrv_7_XX.dll` with `XX`: "ts" or "nts" (thread safe or non-thread safe). I think you need the thread safe version.

Otherwise, use [MS SQL Server (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) PDO driver (read the "Installation" part in the link!) with the [PDO_SQLSRV DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php) (connection string) and the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) general functionality, e.g. common to all drivers. The driver will be added to the php.ini as `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll` then (check the same page for instructions: [Loading the PHP SQL Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver)). If you ask me, I would really choose this option.

**Nota Bene:** Don't forget to restart the web server and/or the db service after each change in configs!

Good luck.