# Connect PHP to Ms SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I have completed all the steps to make a connection between PHP and Ms SQL but still its not working and showing an error of "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()". I have installed MS SQL Driver also. the extension i am using in php.ini is php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll right now but it is not included in xampp extensions. TCP/ IP is also enabled already.

Comment: search on google "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103452/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: I have already checked this link..@GenishParvadia

Comment: I am using this extension on xampp for ms sql in php.ini php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll

Comment: Edit your question. Tell us what you have tried and what is different with your problem and the answers in the links from the comments. With this little information nobody can even start to guess what is wrong

Comment: I have also tried with pdo_sqlsrv but it shows the "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver" whether drivers are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PDO statement to connect 
An example bellow:

```
# Connecting to PostGreSQL
$dbh = new PDO("msql:dbname=$dbname; host=$host", $username, $password);
# Setting an attribute on the database handle and error reporting
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
# Prepares a statement for execution and returns a statement object 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
# Set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
# Returns an array containing all the results from the query
$allRows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```